# How to run phpunit tests with selenium2 on different browsers

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I would like some help with running phpunit tests using selenium2 on multiple browsers.  I have the following phpunit test which runs ok against the Firefox browser. How do I run it against others like Chrome, IE, Opera, Safari?

I have added the testcase below if you can help.  Any links to help sites would be appreciated.

```
class exampleTestcase2 extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase {
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setHost('localhost'); // Set the hostname for the connection to the Selenium server.
        $this->setPort(4444); // set port # for connection to selenium server
        $this->setBrowser('firefox'); // set the browser to be usedRequest State Change
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.php.net/');  // set base URL for tests
    }

    public function testCMS() // Test the title on index page
    {
        $this->currentWindow()->maximize(); // open window in full screen
        $this->url('index.php'); // Set the URL to access the login page            
        $this->assertEquals('PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor', $this->title());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the phpunit command, you can set a environment variable before executing it, and read the value from the test script.

On Mac OS X or Linux, type at the console:

```
export SELENIUM_BROWSER=chrome
```

In Windows:

```
set SELENIUM_BROWSER='chrome'
```

And in the script:

```
$browser = getenv('SELENIUM_BROWSER') ? getenv('SELENIUM_BROWSER') : 'firefox';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change .xml file according to your browser
Remember for firefox geckodriver is requried.

```
<selenium>
    <browser
        name="firefox on Windows"
        browser="firefox"
        host="http://localhost"
        port="4450"
        timeout="40000"/>
</selenium>

<php>
    <const name="PHPUNIT_TESTSUITE" value="true"/>
    <const name="PHPUNIT_TESTSUITE_EXTENSION_SELENIUM_HOST" value="127.0.0.1"/>
    <const name="PHPUNIT_TESTSUITE_EXTENSION_SELENIUM_PORT" value="4445"/>
    <const name="PHPUNIT_TESTSUITE_EXTENSION_SELENIUM_BROWSER" value="firefox"/>
    <const name="PHPUNIT_TESTSUITE_EXTENSION_SELENIUM2_BROWSER" value="firefox"/>
    <const name="PHPUNIT_TESTSUITE_EXTENSION_SELENIUM_TESTS_URL" value="http://test.com/"/>
    <const name="PHPUNIT_TESTSUITE_EXTENSION_SELENIUM_PATH" value="/tmp"/>
</php>
```